# Symfony Assetic Dump get class not Found Exception

Tags: php, symfony, classnotfoundexception

When I tries to assetic dump **php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod**, I got Error Like

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]               
  Attempted to load class "Twig_Filter_Method" from the global namespace.  
  Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

In Browser Run my Project It is display error like :-

```
ClassNotFoundException in BootstrapIconExtension.php line 51: 

Attempted to load class "Twig_Filter_Method" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
```

Anyone have any Suggestion please let me know ..

Comment: Have you updated twig recently? It appears that Twig 2.0 filters are removed including Twig_Filter_Method.

You'll need to give more information to resolve this, such as which version of your framework are you using etc.

Comment: @Greg currenly I used Framework Symfony 2.8

Comment: I believe the twig version of symfony 2.8 is 2+, which would mean the filter of the Extension you've created isn't working. Did you write the BootstrapIconExtension or is it a third party library?

Answer (score 2):

Change

`'apply_filter' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'applyFilter'),`

to this

`'apply_filter'      => new \Twig_SimpleFilter('apply_filter', array($this, 'apply_filter')),`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; for me it was related with the liip imagine bundle version i was using. I have changed that version and it worked smoothly

Comment: Could you add some more background information, please? E.g. which versions have you changed...

Comment: Using now "@stable" for liip imagine in composer.json